# How come the gevent timeout exception is never caught by my except clause?

Tags: python, timeout, gevent

The code never reaches the `print 'never reach1'` or `print 'never reach2'` line when I try to telnet into the server.

```
import sys, signal
from gevent.server import StreamServer
from gevent.pool import Pool
from gevent import monkey
import gevent
from gevent import Timeout
import random

class SocketPool(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = Pool(1000)

    def listen(self, socket):
        while True:
            line = socket.recv(1024)
            print line

    def add_handler(self, socket, address):
        if self.pool.full():
            raise Exception("At maximum pool size")
        else:
            self.pool.spawn(self.listen, socket)
            gevent.spawn(self.wait).join()

    def wait(self):
        try:
            timeout = Timeout(1)
            timeout.start()
        except Timeout:
            print 'never reach1'
        except:
            print 'never reach2'

    def shutdown(self): self.pool.kill()

def signal_handler(signal, frame): sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
monkey.patch_all()
sockPool = SocketPool()
server = StreamServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), sockPool.add_handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.timeout.html#gevent.Timeout):

```
timeout = Timeout(seconds, exception)
timeout.start()
try:
    ...  # exception will be raised here, after *seconds* passed since start() call
finally:
    timeout.cancel()
```

So your `try` block is completely executed and hence cannot catch the exception.
You should put something like a `while` loop or a computation that requires at least 1 second to see the exception.

If you want to make a method that simply "sleeps" without using CPU I'd recommend using a simple `time.sleep` instead of using a `Timeout`.